# WCF XmlSerialization somehow mis-interpreted as DataContract Serialization - post VS 2012 Update1

Tags: wcf, xml-serialization, .net-4.5, datacontractserializer, svcutil.exe

We've a WCF / ASP.NET hosted web service.  The data types in the service contract use XSD.exe generated types, and hence are decorated with `XmlSerialization` attributes.  We created a client for it using SvcUtil, including using the `/ser:XmlSerializer` parameter.  Been working for many years.

We just upgraded our build scripts to use VS 2012, and the v 8.0A Windows/.NET SDK NETFX 4.0 Tools version of SvcUtil.exe (v 4.0.30319.17929).

We are now seeing a strange error message when our client (built w/ VS 2012 and the new 8.0A SvcUtil) attempts to call the WCF service:

`Type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task1[MyNamespace.MyClient.MyDataStructure]' cannot be serialized. Consider marking it with the DataContractAttribute attribute, and marking all of its members you want serialized with the DataMemberAttribute attribute.  If the type is a collection, consider marking it with the CollectionDataContractAttribute.  See the Microsoft .NET Framework documentation for other supported types.`

This error prevents our application from being able to call the WCF service, and we're stuck.

I note that we are not passing a parameter to SvcUtil for `/async`.  I also note that the SvcUtil help for .NET SDK 8.0A (v 4.0.30319.17929) indicates that the default is to `generate synchronous and task-based asynchronous method signatures.`  Is there some built-in disconnect between `System.Threading.Task` and `XmlSerializer` ?

Suggestions for how we can prevent the runtime from somehow thinking we're using `DataContractSerialization` when we intend `XmlSerialization`?

Comment: I see from [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11546431/net-4-5-svcutil-generates-two-operations-with-the-same-name-method-and-methoda) from 
@vossad01 that we could add `/syncOnly` to prevent the `System.Threading.Tasks.Task1` type wrapping construct from generating.  However, what if we wish to use the Task-based asynchronous methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have an answer from Microsoft, posted [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/afdfb613-49cf-44ca-a3a0-b051e644406e).

Short is that `/syncOnly` will be needed if you intend to build with .NET 4.5 `SvcUtil` but target the .NET 4 runtime.